# GFortran on Mac OS BigSur issues, trying to install PHydrus

Tags: gfortran

I have attached an image showing the issue when I try to open up GFortran on my Mac OS Big Sur. I need fortran to compile stuff so I can install PHydrus. I am very bad at computers please help!

I tried to change my mac privacy settings it still didn't work

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please note that we do not see your image. That is probably a good thing. Please do *not* share important information like error messages in an image. Copy and paste it **as text**. It is really very important.

Comment: Also, please understand that this is a programming site, not a general software installation support site. We can only help you with programming problems. For gerneral MacOS software problems use https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/